# Easy resolution to underscore issue in MathJax and Markdown?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, mathjax

I know there are already many questions regarding this issue, but I have not found any that specifically answer my question.

I am building a site using Jekyll (AcademicPages). I have several pages full of mathematical expressions, and the underscores are behaving badly due to the interaction between Markdown and Jekyll.

I am aware that this can be (partially) resolved by escaping the underscores, but I cannot do this for the entire page.

An example can be seen on my testing site [here](https://clementyung.github.io/testing). Here is the markdown file for that page:

```
---
title: "Testing"
collection: archive
type: "Type"
permalink: /testing
excerpt: ""
---

Main paragraph underscore $\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)$.
<ol>
<li>Item underscores $\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)$.</li>
</ol>
    
$$
\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)
$$


Main paragraph underscore $\operatorname{ext}\_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}\_\in(\emptyset)$.
<ol>
<li>Item underscores $\operatorname{ext}\_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}\_\in(\emptyset)$.</li>
</ol>
    
$$
\operatorname{ext}\_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}\_\in(\emptyset)
$$
```

The first half of the page uses `_` while the second half of the page uses `\_`.

- In the first half of the page, the underscores in the main paragraph are badly rendered.
- In the second half the underscores in the list element and math environment are badly rendered.

As my pages are much longer than my testing page, I wish to know if there is an easy way to resolve this problem without having to manually escape the underscores at parts of the page where it is badly rendered.

A few things I have tried but did not work:

1. Putting `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` at the start and end of the body respectively. There were no changes to the page.
2. Putting `<span>` and `</span>` around all expressions of the form `$...$`. It fixes the formatting around the text, but the underscore still disappears from the math expression.
3. Putting `<div>` and `</div>` around all expressions of the form `$...$`. It does nothing.

Comment: Interesting issue. Maybe there are options to completely escape/define such formulas a formulas. Have you found something in the MathJax docs? https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/delimiters.html or does https://hiltmon.com/blog/2017/01/28/mathjax-in-markdown/ help you?

Comment: The test page doesn't seem to be available, so we can't see your MathJax configuration or which version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have managed to mostly resolve the problem by putting the entire page in a `<body>` element. I'll write it out in a little more detail later.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using MathJax v2.7.4, so you may want to update to version 2.7.9, which is the highest v2 release (the `latest.js` from that version no longer works properly, I'm afraid, so you get the 2.7.4 version).  it would be even better to update to version 3, if you can.

Here is a configuration that would allow you to use `` `$...$` `` and `` `$$...$$` `` to delimit in-line and displayed math (note the back-ticks around the dollar signs).

```js
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea"],
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['`$', '$`'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ['`$$', '$$`'], ['\\[', '\\]']]
  }
});
MathJax.Hub.Register.LoadHook("[MathJax]/extensions/tex2jax.js", function () {
  var TEX2JAX = MathJax.Extension.tex2jax;
  TEX2JAX._createMathTag = TEX2JAX.createMathTag;
  TEX2JAX.createMathTag = function (mode, tex) {
    const math = this._createMathTag(mode, tex);
    const code = math.parentNode;
    if (code.nodeName === 'CODE' && code.childNodes.length <= 3) {
      const span = document.createElement('mjx-span');
      code.parentNode.replaceChild(span, code);
      span.appendChild(math);
    }
    return math;
  };
});
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML" defer></script>
```

It handles removing the `<code>` tags that I mentioned, and also gets MathJax from a different CDN where you can request the highest version 2 release more easily.

I'm not sure how you need to configure Jekyll for this, but you should be able to provide a custom configuration, and may be able to replace the actual URL to use for MathJax, so should be able to integrate this into your site.

If you want to use version 3, here is the corresponding configuration:

```js
<script>
MathJax = {
  removeCode(math, doc) {
    const code = math.start.node.parentNode;
    if (code.nodeName === 'CODE' && code.childNodes.length === 1) {
      const span = document.createElement('mjx-span');
      code.parentNode.replaceChild(span, code);
      span.appendChild(code.firstChild);
    }
  },
  options: {
    skipHtmlTags: {'[-]': ['code', 'pre']},
    renderActions: {
      removeCode: [
        11,
        (doc) => {for (const math of MathJax.startup.document.math) MathJax.config.removeCode(math, doc)},
        (math, doc) => MathJax.config.removeCode(math, doc),
        false
      ]
    }
  },
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['`$', '$`'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ['`$$', '$$`'], ['\\[', '\\]']]
  }
};
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js" defer id="MathJax-script"></script>
```

So your test page (with either of these configurations) would look like

```
Main paragraph underscore `$\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)$`.
<ol>
<li>Item underscores `$\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)$`.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to find a way to solve this problem, but unfortunately with no perfect solution until now. A not-so-perfect way is putting `{::nomarkdown}` and `{:/}` around all mathematics expressions.
But I don't think this is a real solution for people dealing with math all day like me, and I'm looking forward to a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to mostly resolve the problem by putting everything after `---` in a `<body>` element. In other words, the following code renders all underscores correctly:

```
---
title: "Testing"
collection: solutions
type: "Type"
permalink: /jech-solutions/testing
excerpt: ""
---
<body>
Main paragraph underscore $\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)$.
<ol>
<li>Item underscores $\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)$.</li>
</ol>
    
$$
\operatorname{ext}_\in(X) = \operatorname{ext}_\in(\emptyset)
$$
</body>
```

These may lead to a few issues - for instance, `## Heading` no longer renders into a heading, and all line breaks must be accompanied by a `<br/>`. However, these are far easier to fix using programming.

Comment: You probably don't have to go to the extent of marking the entire document as raw HTML by using a `<body>` tag.  There are other, less drastic, approaches.  For example, you could use back-ticks around the math and configure MathJax to not skip `<code>` tags when looking for math.  You could even arrange for the `<code>` tags to be removed using MathJax filter or render action (depending on the version you are using).  That's why I was asking for your MathJax configuration and version.  That would allow you to keep using Markdown features like headers.

Comment: @DavideCervone I have included back the testing page. Please see my question. I'm not sure what you mean by back-ticks around the math environment (I'm quite new to HTML,  Markdown etc.).

Comment: In markdown back-ticks (`` ` ``) are used to enclose material that is not processed by Markdown (so should be appear verbatim).  So enclosing the math in back-ticks would prevent the underscores from being processed by Markdown.  But the result is placed in a `<code>` tag, and MathJax usually skips code tags, so you need to configure MathJax to *not* skip them.  Also, code tags are often styled differently from the rest of the text, and that could affect the MathJax output, so it is best to remove the code tags before the math is typeset.  I will write an answer below.